# Smarty - assigning too many variables?

Tags: codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

I'm using Smarty and trying to implement multi-language support on my CodeIgniter site. Is it OK to assign all the possible language variables in one place such that it is available to all pages, regardless of whether the language variable is used or not? This approach is easy, but I am worried about performance impact of having too many variables assigned in Smarty.

Or should I go through the trouble of only assigning language variables needed per page? That would be a pain to implement and maintain, but might not be as expensive for Smarty.

Comment: How many language strings do you estimate to have in the end (in total)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on if you're willing to spend the memory on it.

As far as performance goes, it won't make an appreciable impact (unless you're loading many MB of text... which I think is unlikely). Memory will increase ever so slightly by assigning all the variables at once.

I don't know what your server setup is like, but if you're using something like PHP-FPM, it will increase memory per child process, so that is something to keep in mind. Again though, depending on how much you're storing, it could be close to nothing.